# How to use console with console.dir("string"+object)

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, console, console.log

Here is my code:

```
var foo = {
    age:20
}

console.dir(`hello:${foo}`)
```

I expect

```
hello:{ age: 201 }
```

but I got

```
'hello:[object Object]'
```

and if I don't want use

```
console.log("hello")
console.dir(foo)
```

is there any way to print "hello" and object's content in one console function?

Comment: ```console.dir(`hello:${JSON.stringify(foo)}`)``` will work in most cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.dir` expects an object to be passed, and shows that as a table. `.log` is for logging anything (including strings). Therefore if you want to log a string and an object as a table, you require two different funtionalities, or in other words: two different functions.

If you do that *once*, there is no sense in writing a 3 line function to reduce two lines into one (well four actually). If you however plan to do that more often, well then ...

```
 Object.defineProperty(console, "taggedDir", {
    value(name, table) {
       this.log(name);
       this.dir(table);
    }
});

console.taggedDir("Table:", { /*...*/ });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `JSON.stringify`. What's happening is that when you use the string interpolation `${}`, the `toString` method is called - on an object, the result of this is `[object Object]`:

```js
console.log({}.toString());
```

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) converts an object or array to a string, but keeps the content and avoids the `toString` output. So just use it like so:

```js
var foo = {
  age: 20
};

console.dir(`hello:${JSON.stringify(foo)}`)
```

Also note that `dir` is used for showing the different properties of objects. It's better to just use `console.log`, which means you can avoid `JSON.stringify` altogether:

```js
var foo = {
  age: 20
};

console.log("hello:", foo);
```

Comment: I'd never use JSON.stringify. It removes functions, symbols, the prototype, etc. etc. and is therefore not useful at all. Logging the object directly is way better in terms of usability.